# WebSocket java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: spring

I have a problem with websocket on java server side during handshake. Server is thrown me exception

**java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$UnmodifiableEntry.setValue(Unknown Source)**

I'm not using spring boot and version is 4.2.6

[error](http://prntscr.com/sauyiv)

I've used code from WebSocket Support offical documentation

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic" , "/queue");

}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    registry.addEndpoint("/appoint").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();

}
```

Could someone have any idea what is happening and to give me some idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you find anything on this?